# Issue installing anaconda

Tags: software-installation, anaconda

I tried installing anaconda3 today but was returned the following error message:

```
Preparing transaction: done
Executing transaction: / WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(46): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.
  environment location: /home/hshows/anaconda3
  registry file: /home/hshows/.conda/environments.txt
done
installation finished.
Do you wish the installer to initialize Anaconda3
by running conda init? [yes|no]
```

I'm a stark raving noob at ubuntu so I'm not sure where to start with resolving this issue.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

It *seems* anaconda installed properly (e.g. I am able to open a jupyter notebook), however I still would like to understand the "warning" mentioned above. Additionally when I open a new terminal now I get the word (base) in front of my terminal prompt--is this perhaps related to the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is an error with the anaconda installer, reported here :

https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11148

The suggested fix is to manually create the `~/.conda` folder before running the installer. The GitHub issues indicates this is fixed but I had the same error today installing miniconda3.

**EDIT**
One of the maintainers [indicated](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11148#issuecomment-536037433) that the miniconda installer will be updated within 1-2 weeks. The Anaconda installer is already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The base terminal prompt issue has nothing to due with the error message and can be resolved by setting:

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

Comment: Thank you Kulfy for the correction.